# ValueError while plotting line chart in python script

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Below is my python script where I am trying to generate line charts with csv file as input.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('out1.csv',delimiter=',')
current = data['Violations']
previous = data['Violations1']
past = data['Violations2']
ip = data['VER']
fig = plt.figure()
myaxes = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,1.6,1.6])
myaxes.plot(ip,current)
```

When I am trying to execute I am getting error as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tr.py", line 26, in <module>
    myaxes.plot(ip, current)
  File "/tool/pandora64/.package/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1892, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tool/pandora64/.package/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1407, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "/tool/pandora64/.package/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1787, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "/tool/pandora64/.package/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1809, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "/tool/pandora64/.package/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 989, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "/tool/pandora64/.package/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 676, in recache
    x = np.asarray(xconv, np.float_)
  File "/tool/pandora64/.package/python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: DC
```

May I know what went wrong in my code.
Below is my input file

[image]

```
VER Violations  Violations  Violations
DC  20          20          40
VDCI    56          45          56
SIN 90          40          76
UMC 67          30          50
CHNL    34          68          90
DUTT    67          67          40
PAST    56          30          30
FUT 20          70          50
```

Comment: I tried the code in Google Colab. Why is the VER column a float type? Let's check the data at hand.

Comment: Your code actually works fine for me

Comment: @r-beginners I am executing my code like script python script.py. I used your code but still facing issue.                                         
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sf.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: @xjcl, yes the code is working fine in IDE. But when I am executing it in my linux host through script then I am facing issue.

Comment: @xjcl, is issue is with my csv file.

Comment: @Rama could you paste the csv file? I made one based on the table you posted and that one was fine.

Comment: @xjcl, please find below                                                                                                             VER Violations Violations Violations
DC         20 20  40
VDCI 56 45 56
SIN        90 40 76
UMC 67 30 50
CHNL 34 68 90
DUTT 67 67 40
PAST 56 30 30
FUT         20 70 50

Comment: I need it with the original formatting. But as I said, I cannot reproduce it. Can you post all lines from the traceback/error?

Comment: @xjcl, I pasted the entire error and my csv. Can you please help.

Comment: @Rama I'm getting `KeyError: 'Violations'` because the csv is using tabs for separation instead of commas like your code is. Can you please ensure that you are posting the actual code and the actual input csv.